# How it is possible to use jodd.http.HttpRequest to load a page content that is generated by javascript?

Tags: jodd, jodd-lagarto

I try to load a page content with:

```
HttpResponse response2 = HttpRequest.get(_PAGE_URL).cookies(response.cookies()).send();
```

In a browser, the page source is full of javascript to generate the DOM, but in the Web Inspector of the browser I can see the generated source.

The question is, can I somehow retrieved the generated page content by Jodd's utilities?

Comment: Check my edited answer - you can use Selenium driver, which works quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can just download the static HTML content (as you did) and then you would need to *render* it using some other tool.

Since Java 8, you can use JavaFX's WebView Component (as far as I remember), but please search for other tools as well (maybe [cef](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/java-cef)?)

EDIT
See: https://github.com/igr/web-scraper (based on Selenium WebDriver). One thing I miss is better control over request/response.

There is also HtmlUnit, but from the reviews, it seems Selenium is a better choice.